# Understanding a code for deep learning NOMA system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, training-data

I'm trying very hard to understand this code about a Deep Learning-Based NOMA system based in MATLAB. I am really new to MATLAB coding but I really need to understand this entire code as it will help in my school project and I am struggling.

I think as of right now I do not need to know how the mathematical formulas work, but instead, the focus is on what the code is doing and its flow.

[This is part of the code in the trainData.m file that I am struggling with right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahz1k.png)

1. Why are the pilot symbols calculated and then replaced right after?
2. Why is the idx_sc (20) selected to be replaced? What is its significance? Is it the only subcarrier selected for the training of the DL model? Why only that?
3. This portion of the code in the picture is labeled "generate training data for each class". From my understanding, it is generating OFDM packets for each label, simulating the transmission and reception, and then getting the features and labels for each of the 16 classes. Is that correct?

The code and all relevant function files can be found in the link below.

Please help me understand the code!!! Please! Much thanks!

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/75478-deep-learning-for-signal-detection-in-noma-systems

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, In lines 91 the code initializes the entire variable as 0. Subsequent lines (92-96) are just replacing pieces of the variable based on the indexing inside the “(…)”